# Express Routes Generating 404 Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, routes

I'm using MEAN stack as an extension of my learning node and express. What I'm attempting to do is simply link from one static page to another within the app.

My routes are defined as:

```
//Home route
var index = require('../app/controllers/index');
app.get('/', index.render);

//Shop Redirect
var shop = require('../app/controllers/shop');
app.get('/shop', shop.render);
```

I can test to make sure the shop view is working correctly by changing the Home Route to use the shop view. Everything there is fine. All of the previously defined views within mean.io work correctly as well. I've tried shutting everything down, doing a hard reset, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that Angular handled the routes before express handled the routes. The solution was to look at the config.js file in /public/js/config.js and add:

```
    when('/shop', {
        templateUrl: 'views/index.html'
    }).
```